# Is there Vector3Int equivalentin XNA?

Tags: xna

I wonder if there is a Unity's `Vector3Int` equivalent in XNA. I don't want to use *Vector3* to store three integers in one structure, yet I don't want to create my own class. Is there a structure (like *Point*<->*Vector2* or *Rectangle*<->*Vector4*) for *Vector3*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  `Point` is a carryover from `System.Drawing` and `Rectangle` helps with AABB collisions.

The only caveat to storing integers in floats(they consume the same memory amount) is the possible loss of precision since floats cannot precisely store some values. In most instances this is not a problem. Floating point arithmetic can be slower than integer arithmetic operations.

I would suggest creating a `Vector3Int` struct:

```
public struct Vector3Int
{
   public int X;
   public int Y;
   public int Z;

   public Vector3Int()
   {
     X = 0;
     Y = 0;
     Z = 0;
   }
   public Vector3Int(int val)
   {
     X = val;
     Y = val;
     Z = val;
   }
   public Vector3Int(int x, int y, int z)
   {
     X = x;
     Y = y;
     Z = z;
   }
}
```

This has the advantages of a struct since it is stored on the stack.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there will be something, but I guess I am stuck with making own struct :) Thank you very much